# How to use variable hoisting with function expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, hoisting

I understand that variable hoisting is the behavior of moving declaration to the top of the function or global context.
This is shown in the code below:

```
console.log(a);
var a = 'Hello World!';
```

The above code actually gets the following behavior:

```
var a;
console.log(a);
a = 'Hello World!';
```

The resulting output from the above code is `undefined`.

In above example, it is important to note that variable hoisting moves only the declaration part at the top. The initialization part is not moved at the top.

When I am trying to replicate the same behavior using function expression, I am getting an unexpected output.

This is shown in code below:

```
function sayHello() {
    var say = function() { console.log(hello); }
    var hello= 'Hello World !!';
    return say;
}
sayHello()(); // output Hello World !!
```

I am trying to understand why we have not received `undefined` as an output because the variable `hello` is initialized only after it is used (similar to the previous example).

Comment: That's example 5 of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work
The closure captures the variable reference (so to speak), not the value at the time of creation.

Comment: I don't think the comparison is fair. On one hand, you have a function that isn't invoked until after a var is initialized, and in another case, it's clearly uninitialized. The results don't seem surprising to me.

Comment: But here it's also not invoked before `hello` is initialized...

Comment: Exactly--seems like when `sayHello()` is called, everything in the closure is initialized, including `hello`. Then, `say` is invoked and of course it finds that `hello` has the value `"Hello World !!"` in its enclosing scope as we'd expect.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying... Seems I misunderstood what you meant. I thought you referred to the comparison to example 5 in the other answer, and then I read your `isn't` as `is`. Never mind

Comment: *"*initialized only after it is used*" - no. The word "after" here is temporal, not spacial. It doesn't mean "below", but "later".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you see comes from how closures work. It's not that the value of `hello` somehow gets hoisted, it's that the code that reads the value of `hello` (the `console.log(hello)` part) is only executed after you set the value!

To not get confused here with the hoisting, since that is not really relevant to what you are seeing, let's write out the code in the way it would look after hoisting:

```js
function sayHello() {
    var hello;
    var say = function() { console.log(hello); }
    hello = 'Hello World !!';
    return say;
}
sayHello()(); // output Hello World !!
```

If you would insert a `say()` before the line `hello = 'Hello World !!';` it would print `undefined`.

Now, when you have code like this...

```js
    var hello;
    var say = function() { console.log(hello); }
```

...then the `hello` inside `say` is not a copy of the outside `hello`, it's actually the same variable you are referencing here. And it continues existing even after the outer functioned returned, because now you have a reference to the `say` function which in turn still keeps a reference to `hello`.

> I am trying to understand why we have not received `undefined` as an output because the variable `hello` **is initialized only after it is used** (similar to the previous example).

I think this is your misunderstanding. It is used when you call the `say` function at the very end - chronologically speaking. The fact that looking at the code from top to bottom `hello` appears to be "used" before doesn't matter, because that's not the order in which the code executes. At the line `var say = function () { console.log(hello); }` you just do `var say = something;`, the `something` doesn't have any meaning at that point (it just has to be syntactially correct). The access to `hello` occurs only when you call `say` at the end.

(You could also try with something like `var say = function () { derp(); }`, and you'd notice that you get the error `derp is not defined` only when you call that function, not when you define it.)

So, chronologically, this is what happens:

- `sayHello` is called
- `hello` is created and contains `undefined`
- `say` is created and assigned a function expression with body `console.log(hello)`
- `hello` is assigned `"Hello World !!"`
- `sayHello` returns `say`
- The function expression (which was `say`) is called
- `console.log(hello)` executes

  - Remember that `hello` contains `"Hello World !!"` at that point
- The string `"Hello World !!"` gets printed

You can expand this example, to help understanding:

```js
function sayHello() {
  var hello;
  var say = function() { console.log(hello); }  
  hello = 'Hello World !!';
  var think = function() { hello = 'What should I think about?'; }
  return [say, think];
}

var [say, think] = sayHello();
say(); // Prints "Hello World !!";
think();
say(); // prints "What should I think about?"
```

As you can see, `hello` just lives on and can be used by both `say` and `think`, even after `sayHello` returned, all of these parts of the code reference the same `hello` variable.